# masking zero columns in numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do the following, just misunderstand where I'm wrong:

```
In: import numpy as np

In: a  = np.array([[0., 1., 0.],
             [1., 2., 0.],
             [0., 3., 0.]]) 

In: for i in range(a.shape[1]):
        a[:, i] = np.ma.masked_where(~a[:, i].any(), a[:, i])

Out: array([[0., 1., --],
     [1., 2., --],
     [0., 3., --]])
```

The point here is to mask only the third column because it's completely zeros, and leave the first column zeros unmasked

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: `---` is not a valid Python identifier.

Comment: perhaps updating the question and removing the comments?

Comment: @Alex `--` is what NumPy will output when a value is masked.

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question, but I assume your question is: why are there (still) two non-masked zeros in the final output. But please update your question with your actual question.

Comment: Your problem likely lies in the fact that you can't safely invert floating point numbers (`~a` will throw an error).

Comment: Yes - from the OP I would like to know if you *wanted* the first row to remain unmasked (because not every entry is zero) OR if you wanted to mask it. Because if you want to mask all zeros if your array simply use `a_mask = np.ma.masked_where(a <= 0, a)`

Comment: Yes, that's the point to leave the first column untouched, because it' not completely zeros, that's why I have to use for loop and I don't see another decision right now

Answer (score 0):

One approach to mask based on all zeros in a column is simply to identify column *sums* of zero. Below is my solution, borrowing very heavily off of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611250/mask-specific-columns-of-a-numpy-array) to provide a simple mechanism for masking after you have gotten the column indices of interest.

```
import numpy as np    

def mask_zero_cols(in_array):
    # idx is an array of column indices for all-zero columns
    idx = np.where(in_array.sum(axis=0) == 0)[0] #axis=0 is for columns
    m = np.zeros_like(in_array)
    m[:, idx] = 1

    return np.ma.masked_array(in_array, m)


a = np.array([[0., 1., 0.],
             [1., 2., 0.],
             [0., 3., 0.]])

a_mask = mask_zero_cols(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't invert (`~`) floating point numbers and arrays.

Try with:

```
a = np.ma.masked_where(np.isclose(a, 0), a)
```

(no for loop needed either.)